# Treating Warnings as Errors

Tags: php, warnings, callstack

I have a php application that I have just re-factored. Unfortunately it spewing out warnings like:

> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /home/yacoby/dev/netbeans/php/Zend/Db/Select.php on line 776

Which is impossible (or very hard work) to work out the issue as I don't have a callstack so can't tell which parts of my code are causing the warning and there is a lot of code.

I need a method to either treat warnings like errors (In that the application dies and prints the stacktrace) or I need the stacktrace to be shown when printing errors. Is there a method to do this?

Comment: XDebug speaks about such a feature here http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace

Comment: XDebug answer was accepted as it produced the best stacktrace (plus it had clickable links in my IDE ;) ). All others got +1 as well for good answers which all worked fine.

Answer (score 30):

See example #1 at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php

```
<?php
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

/* Trigger exception */
strpos();
?>
```

Comment: I think this is how PHPUnit does it to turn regular errors, notices and warnings into PHPUnit Framework error/notice/warning exceptions.

Comment: Don't know if it's "cool", but it's definately the easiest. :P

Comment: Shows more errors, but doesn't show a stacktrace on Warnings, for me.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at [`set_error_handler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and include this at the beginning of your scripts or in your bootstrap to just print the stacktrace when E_WARNINGs occur.

```
function stacktrace_error_handler($errno,$message,$file,$line,$context)
{
    if($errno === E_WARNING) {
        debug_print_backtrace();
    }
    return false; // to execute the regular error handler
}
set_error_handler("stacktrace_error_handler");
```

For more control over the various types, have a look at the more explicit version posted elsewhere in the answers.

Comment: Works, but the output uses newlines instead of <br>, so it is difficult to read in HTML.

Comment: Here is code for output in HTML:

function GetStack()
 {
 return (new Exception())->getTraceAsString();
 } // GetStack

function stacktrace_error_handler($errno,$message,$file,$line,$context)
{
    if($errno === E_WARNING) {
   echo nl2br(GetStack());
    }
    return false; // to execute the regular error handler
}
set_error_handler("stacktrace_error_handler");

Comment: Here is code for output in HTML:

`function GetStack()
 {
 return (new Exception())->getTraceAsString();
 } // GetStack

function stacktrace_error_handler($errno,$message,$file,$line,$context)
{
    if($errno === E_WARNING) {
   echo nl2br(GetStack());
    }
    return false; // to execute the regular error handler
}
set_error_handler("stacktrace_error_handler");
`

Comment: Or just wrap it in `<pre>` tags and `htmlspecialchars()`. @DavidSpector.

Answer (score 4):

You can define your own error handler using set_error_handler()

In the handler function you can treat each class of error however you want. Here's a basic template that I use, in my case I only want to handle fatal errors, so I ignore notices and warnings.

In your case you could do a backtrace on warnings, or log them however you want

```
function error_handler($errno,$message,$file,$line,$context) {

switch($errno) {
    // ignore warnings and notices
    case E_WARNING:
    case E_NOTICE:
    case E_USER_NOTICE:
    case E_USER_WARNING:
        break;
    // log PHP and user errors
    case E_ERROR:
    case E_USER_ERROR:
              // Do some processing on fatal errors
    }
}
```

Comment: The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function: **E_ERROR**, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the file where set_error_handler() is called. - But I upvoted nonetheless.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info. I normally used this for handling USER_ERROR but wasn't aware it couldn't catch E_ERROR, although it does make sense when you think about it.