# Only variables should be passed by reference php 5.4 vs php 5.5 Is it settings?

Tags: php

In php 5.4.32 the following line produces this fatal error:

```
....views/sales/register.php: 493","() Only variables should be passed by reference"
```

In php 5.5.14 it does not produce an error.

Is there a setting in php.ini that would cause this to give a fatal error in one install and not the other?

I forgot to post that oops I thought I typed it in:

```
<td class="right"><?php echo to_currency($this->Giftcard->get_giftcard_value(end(explode(':', $payment['payment_type']))) - $payment['payment_amount']);?></td>
```

I am not asking WHY it is wrong, but how to reproduce.

EDIT: 
New question:

**How do I make php 5.5 produce a fatal error when "Only variables should be passed by reference" happens.**

I want to have as much errors as possible in development mode to support as many php platforms as possible.

Comment: And line 493 is? With your rep, you should know better ...

Comment: I have posted. I am not asking WHY it is wrong, but how to reproduce in php 5.5

Comment: Are you saying it produces the desired result in PHP 5.5? Or does it also crash? Maybe you haven't activated full error reporting in your PHP 5.5 install.

Comment: Chris, I meant you should know better than forget to post line 493. :)

Comment: In php 5.5 it is NOT a fatal error (it still is an error if I look in logs, but in php 5.4 it is a fatal error.

Comment: See question for new question based on these results.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have E_STRICT turned off or on?

If it is on - it should warn against this problem

[What does E_STRICT do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245859/what-does-e-strict-do)

For warnings as errors, see here:

[Treating Warnings as Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071024/treating-warnings-as-errors)

Also check your display errors maybe?

Comment: In php 5.5 I have E_ALL set which according to php.net should include that. My main complaint is that it produces a fatal error in php 5.4 but NOT in php 5.5. I am thinking there is another setting that changes the fatal nature of such errors

Comment: Darn..After all this work I realized the person was a debug script had a die() in the script when it caught the error making it look like a fatal error. Sorry for all of this.

Comment: Huh, I downvoted you initially thinking `E_STRICT` was irrelevant, but just retracted it. Something interesting I've learned from this thread - whether passing a non-variable by reference is a fatal error or an E_STRICT depends upon *what* you pass. Passing a literal (`function foo (&$bar) {}; foo('die');`) is fatal, but passing the result of a function call is only an `E_STRICT` (`function foo (&$bar) {}; foo(time());`). What a ridiculous language PHP is. I'll update that answer of mine you've linked to.

Comment: @MarkAmery I agree. Php is a horrendously ridiculous language. I hate working in it. But it pays the bills at the moment.