PHP Request Startup: Unknown modifier ','
My team and I have recently installed a monitoring platform (NewRelic) and are receiving the titular warning on every single request in our system:
E_WARNING: PHP Request Startup: Unknown modifier ','

We have recently underwent a platform upgrade moves our stack into Docker, as well as upgrading our language from PHP 7.2 to PHP 8.2. This seems to fire on every page load, on every backend/Ajax request. It is giving us a 100% error rate, but only on our deployed system.
In our php.ini, we have display_errors and display_startup_errors set to off. We are not doing any special regex or grep which would have that type of delimiter (as many of the questions on here point to bad-delimited string searches). I have gone through the other questions and none of them mention startup errors such as this. I also have tried turning on the startup errors and it does not provide me with anything more informative.
I know I could try to suppress or ignore the error, but I would rather resolve this if possible.

Update: Oct 28th
As per the comments, I have searched my code for any instance of a regular expression ending in the /, syntax, and have confirmed that there are no files being loaded through the php.ini as a global includes. I have gone through my controller by breakpoint and have found nothing referencing a regular expression bounded by the comma.
This issue appears even when loading a file with a file only containing a single-line phpinfo(); call, so it is nothing from the code and must come from an ini or something processing before the scripts run.

I recognize this is a vague question, but if there were any additional specifics I could provide I would. This one is fully lost into the ether as to where this would be running. No code to debug; just jimmies to be rustled.

I think Unknown modifier comes from the preg_XXX functions. The modifiers are the characters after the ending delimiter, e.g. /foo/i has the modifier i. So if you have a regular expression like /foo/, you'll get this message from any preg function.

If it's happening for every request, it's presumably coming from a script that runs every time. Do you have an include/require file that all your scripts load? If not, you might have auto_prepend_file configured in your php.ini.

"but only on our deployed system" - what's the difference between the "deployed" system and any other? What's the minimal code that triggers this problem?

Good question @NicoHaase; from what I can tell, the difference between the deployed system and the local is related to OPCache, and this error appears when I simplify the problem and run a file with a single phpinfo() call.

The only place that 'Unknown modifier' exists in the PHP source in for PCRE errors, so it has to be a regex pattern as stated. What lines of your php.ini have you changed/added from the default? Do you get the error from the cli with php -r 'phpinfo();'? Do you get the error from the cli with php -n -r 'phpinfo();'?

have recently installed a monitoring platform (NewRelic) + but only on our deployed system. - sounds like it’s not in the app code but an extension that’s responsible, quite possibly NRs. I suggest to disable extensions to find the one responsible.

Turn warnings into errors so you will get the stacktrace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071024/treating-warnings-as-errors
